# Identifying a mythical creature

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures, mythohistory, superstition

I had a dream one day where i was being stalked through a house by a creature made of twigs. Initially the creature was normal height about 6ft with a face like the chester cat but with normal pupils. I hid in a cubby made for towels in the top of a closet suddenly the door opens and a cat seemed to be floating around the room while laying down but he had branches coming out from under him meowing in a deep distorted voice. The cat went away but then the creature rose up to face me at a height of around 8 to 9 ft. Imagine if cousin it was made of twigs with some sticking out while sporting a chester cat smile with bulging eyes filled with a silent rage a cold murderous stare. When i drew it out and showed it to my father figure at the time he said it wasn't the first time i had drew that same creature. If anybody has any idea of any creature from folklore that might fit this description I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is pretty open-ended. How about the wicker man (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicker_man) Since it was large and made of sticks? Black stick men are dreamlike (https://obscurban-legend.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Stick_Men) Just a few thoughts.

Comment: If you drew it, could you post the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Might be the green man? Not sure how much mythological basis there is, but he shows up on a lot of cathedrals among the grotesques. [image]

Comment: Sol that might actually be it once i did some research into that it kinda makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The creature could be a s spriggan or sprɪdʒən. But as for the cat I do not know, it may be a familiar or similar kind of spirit but to be travelling with a sprɪdʒən would be strange and their are guardians more than anything